# Azure IOT Edge - Large messages

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

What is the best practise for sending larger messages from an edge module, to Azure?, should you use file upload in IoT hub, or go directly to a storage on the side?

/Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fileupload directly via the SDK and IoT Hub is only available for IoT (non Edge) devices, as you already figured out.

You can use the Blob Storage module and deploy it on the edge. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-blob?view=iotedge-2020-11

To upload files, you then add them to the local blob storage and the module will deal with sending it to the Azure Blob storage account.

Comment: Fileupload can be used for Edge Devices via REST APIs

Comment: It can. In that case you have to deal with the Authentication. Using the Blob Storage module (or IoT SDK file upload) will handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to either use the SDK or Blob Storage module as the authentication to blob storage is handled in a more secure way.  The SDK will generate a short lived SAS token to connect to blob storage, and the edge module will send the blob storage connection string down as part of the module twin.